# Porque queda Valor null después de ser eliminado un usuario de una collections? mongodb CRUD API REST

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, crud, delete

**Estoy haciendo un delete de un usuario y funciona colocando su id en req.params.id Sin embargo al volver a hacer el delete al mismo id envía un null,** quiero saber si es posible hacer una manejo de errores que me devuelva usuario no existe y no simplemente null **Al hacer get del usuario eliminado también indica null y quiero enviar un error de usuario no encontrado** cómo puedo hacer para retornar un error y no simplemente null.

Aqui el ejemplo que tengo:

```js
// eliminar Usuario
router.delete("/usuario/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    UsuarioSchema
    .findByIdAndRemove({ _id: id })
    .then((data) => await = res.status(200).send("usuario eliminado con exito" + data))
    .catch((error) => res.status(404).send("usuario no encontrado" + error));
    });
```

Este codigo me funciona, elimina un usuario de mi base de datos, pero cuando lo vuelvo a ejecutar no me da un error, me envia un status 200 pero con usuario null. Por eso quiero agregarle un manejo de errores que si el usuario es null tambien me diga que no existe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Falta ver qué tipo de consultas estás haciendo a MongoDB. Te invito a leer [ask], a realizar el [tour] y a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio. Si tengo que leer, porque estoy empezando en esta comunidad. Muchas gracias por los enlaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encontrar un dato no significa que hubo un error(de manera nativa). Debes especificar que mande un error.

```
router.delete("/usuario/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    UsuarioSchema
    .findByIdAndRemove({ _id: id })
    .then((data) => { 
        if (!data) throw "No existe el usuario o lo que sea"
        res.status(200).send("usuario eliminado con exito" + data))
      }
    .catch((error) => res.status(404).send("usuario no encontrado" + error));
    });

``
```

Comment: Excelente es justo eso lo que quiero que haga, gracias por la aclaración Legna. No conocía el throw, me parece ideal. Sin embargo, ahí te deje un capture, estoy teniendo algunos errores en la sintaxis que no logro resolver, intento corregirlos como indica el vsc pero me siguen dando error. Si pudieras ayudarme con algun enlace o documentación. para aprender mejor como corregir este tipo de errores de sintaxis te lo agradezco. Estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: @JonathanAguiar: las ediciones son para correcciones y mejoras, no para dirigirte al autor de la respuesta o pregunta. Si tienes errores, hazle saber a través de comentarios.

Comment: @JonathanAguiar, solo agrega `;` al final de las sentencias. Ya edite la pregunta. Sobre eso, es sintaxys.